# sublime text color scheme for PHP variables

Tags: php, sublimetext3, sublimetext2

I'm trying to create something that will color my variables in PHP.  I cannot seem to find any themes that do this already in Sublime Text 2 or 3.  I have "PHP" selected as a code type.

I found at minimum I am able to color the dollar sign in `$foo` with this code:

```
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Variable start</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>punctuation.definition.variable</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>fontStyle</key>
        <string>bold</string>
        <key>foreground</key>
        <string>#a08bfd</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

While this changes the literal dollar sign, it does not affect the text after it.  How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Add this block code to set the color of the rest of var :

```
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Variables</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>variable</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#a08bfd</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```